# overwriting resource model class in magento

Tags: magento, overwrite

I am overwriting **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection** class to **Namespace_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection** to overwrite a protected function(*_preparePriceExpressionParameters*).

this is code I wrote in config.xml to overwrite this class file.

```
<models>
    <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                    <resource_product_collection>Namespace_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</resource_product_collection>
            </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</models>
```

but it does not work, then I changed the code as below but this also does not work.

```
<models>
    <catalog_resource_product>
        <rewrite>
            <collection>Namespace_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</collection>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog_resource_product>
</models>
```

can any one have the idea what I made wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the node above the `rewrite` has to match the `<resourceModel>` from the model you want to overwrite, so:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <namespace_catalog>
            <class>Namespace_Catalog_Model</class>
        </namespace_catalog>
        <catalog_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <product_collection>Namespace_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</product_collection>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: <namespace_catalog>
  <class>Namespace_Catalog_Model</class>
</namespace_catalog>
I already have these lines.

Comment: @SankarRaj the problem is in the node around your `<rewrite>` one, look at the code I gave you

Answer (score 0):

The last one should be fine. Maybe another module is already overwriting `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` which conflicts with your overwrite.